# Limpar Modal Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

Como posso limpar os dados do modal, as vezes o usuário digita os dados, porém não salva, e se ele abre o modal de novo, os dados estão lá, gostaria de limpar esses dados, como devo proceder? As vezes também acontece de salvar, e ao clicar para adicionar o novo dado, os dados antigos que foram salvos ainda estão no modal.
Segue o código do meu modal:

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="grid-10">
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Cadastrar Banco</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <br />
          <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Nome"></asp:Label>
          <asp:TextBox ID="txtNome" runat="server" CssClass="radiusInput"></asp:TextBox>
          <br />
          <br />
          <br />
          <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Número"></asp:Label>
          <asp:TextBox ID="txtNumero" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
          <br />
          <br />
          <br />
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Gravar" CssClass="radiusInput" OnClick="Button1_Click1" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode limpar os `inputs` após o evento [hidden.bs.modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events) ser chamado.

Um exemplo simples seria isto:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
    console.log('fechar modal')
    $(this).find('input:text').val('');
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-large" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".modal">Launch demo modal</a>

<div class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="nome" />
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Número" />
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ele limpa os dados, porém limpa até o que está escrito no button, gostaria que limpasse somente os textbox.

Comment: @marianac_costa Editei a resposta selecionando somente os `inputs` que são do tipo texto. Veja se lhe atende agora. Caso possua algum campo específico, você pode utilizar algum tipo de selector, como o id ou a classe. Algo como `$('#txtNome').val(' ')`.

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o evento `hidden.bs.modal` do modal da para limpar os dados quando o mesmo for ocultado, da seguinte forma:

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
     // Seu código aqui..
})
```